# how to use generic class in View as model :ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class like belowe:

```
public class DropdownResultViewModel<T, K>
{...}
```

and I used it in View as model like belowe:

```
@model ViewModel.DropdownResultViewModel<City,Guid>
```

I dont want set static Argument  instead `T` and `K` so for this I created an Interface like belowe :

```
public  interface IViewModel
{
}
```

and city inherit it like belowe:

```
public class city :IViewModel{...}
```

and change model in view like belowe :

```
@model ViewModel.DropdownResultViewModel<IViewModel,Guid>
```

but I dont know how about GUID ?
some times maybe instead Guid pass `int` or another .
how can I do this ?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1687165.aspx?Generic+models+in+Razor+views

Comment: @DanielvanHeerden Comments on that page mostly disagree with this design and call it nonsense but I think being able to use generic models for views could be useful in some scenarios. Suppose you want to pass your derived-from-generic-class model from a view to a partial view with that generic-class model.